# Is it possible to independently use Highcharts Navigator without displaying the main chart?

Tags: highcharts, navigator

I would like display the High Chart Navigator only, without having to display the main chart. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use only the navigator from Highstock. You need to only hide all other elements and adapt the chart's height. To connect a selection action with some business logic, use `afterSetExtremes` event.

```
  rangeSelector: {
    enabled: false
  },
  yAxis: {
    visible: false
  },
  xAxis: {
    visible: false,
    events: {
      afterSetExtremes: function(e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    }
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4zkm1vy6/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/navigator